# curve_fit or polyfit? log or no log transform?

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I have two equations which I do fit independently

Equation 1:

```
y = a * exp(-x*b)
```

in which I have all the variables except (b). I currently log transform it into

```
Log(y/a) = -x * b
```

then I fit for -x * b using curve_fit(), I get acceptable results as it is supposed to be a linear relation. I want to know if I shouldn't do the log transform or should I use polyfit instead?

Equation 2:

```
y = a * exp(-x*b) + (x **2)* (b **2) * c/6)
```

I also have y,x and a and want to calculate b and c.

I use log(y/a) as my ydata and curve_fit as follows:

```
v1, v2, v3, v4 = 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000

xdata = np.array([50,300,600,1000])

D_map = np.zeros((n,d,d))
K_map = np.zeros((n,d,d))

def kurtosis(x, D, K):
    return (-x * b) + ((x **2)* (b **2) * c/6)

for i in range(n):
    for r in range(d):
        for c in range(d):
            v1 = b50_data[i,r,c]
            v2 = b300_data[i,r,c]
            v3 = b600_data[i,r,c]
            v4 = b1000_data[i,r,c]
            ydata = np.array([v1,v2, v3, v4])
            ydata = np.log(ydata/v1)

            popt, pcov = curve_fit(kurtosis, xdata, ydata)
            D_map[i,r,c] = popt[0] 
            K_map[i,r,c] = popt[1]
```

I have problems with the 2nd unknown (c). I can only improve the result when setting bounds (It is supposed to be between 0 and 2) for it but still too many missing data (set to the min or the max bound and few data in between)

Should I not use the log transform as it makes the initial values too small for curve_fit? How can I find a suitable initial guess for every dataset in my loop?

Comment: It depends on your data. polyfit of degree 1 (linear) or higher degree to get a better fit? curve_fit if you need a certain curve, polyfit if the data is polynomial or high degree if you can't find an equation.

Comment: Initial guess based on experience? Or are you using completely different ranges all the time? Or you could use a linear fit first to get a general trend, it your data allows for that. You basically need to look at your data and find out how to make a good guess.

Comment: Initial guess based on the results of equation 1. b in Eq1 is supposed to be very close to b in Eq 2, with a shift of the right end of the curve upwards with a factor of c. So if Eq1 is linear, Eq2 should plot a curve that flattens towards the right end of x-axis and c is the measure of the deviation from the linear fit.

Comment: Any sources do you recommend that can help me to understand more what I need for my data?

Comment: Don't know any sources, just look at your data and look at different function shapes. You can post some images here if you like. https://www.chegg.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/14/2015/08/math-55.png Look at polynomial shapes, Zernike polynomials, Bézier curves. Could be trigonometric functions, you could try Fourier decomposition. https://getintoadigitalworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Functions.jpg  Could be some kind of distibution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions